# java parse_str alternative - for http response

Tags: java, parsing, httpresponse

Facebook server side login sends response in the format:

```
access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN&expires=NUMBER_OF_SECONDS_UNTIL_TOKEN_EXPIRES
```

Is there a way to parse this conveniently in Java, other than writing custom code? Something like [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) in PHP.

EDIT: This question has nothing to do with query string or request, It is about parsing request body in the above format.

Comment: Even if it weren't closed as "duplicate", it doesn't say enough of what you want to do. Can you expand *on what you want to do* specifically. Start by provide examples of original data, and how you want it to look.

Comment: The question is quite simple. I want to parse an HTTP **response** where the body of the response is in the given format. Obviously I can write custom code as @gerrytan suggested, but I want to know if there is some Java class that already handles this parsing.

Comment: Your comment *makes sense*, but your question doesn't; as a suggestion: I think you should reword your question to match what you've said in the comment above. Now, to answer your question: No, there doesn't seem to be any built-in class/functions that will accomplish this, **however** (!), there is an [Apache HTTPMessageParser](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/io/HttpMessageParser.html) which seems to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple parser using string split method and a map, something like this:

```
Map<String,String> fbParam = new HashMap<String,String> ();
String[] pairs = fbResp.split("&");
for(String pair : pairs) {
  String[] keyval = pair.split("=");
  fbParam.put(keyval[0], keyval[1]);
}
```

Comment: Actually that is what I would do, but it seems strange there's no in-built way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a Java EE environment, you could use [`ServletRequest.getParameter()`](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html).

You might also consider using the [Web4J Framework](http://www.web4j.com/)'s request parser.

Comment: I want to do this for response, not request